# Declaring a cl_uint variable in OpenCL C leads to Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

I have written a code in OpenCL C to list all the available platforms.

```
int main()
{
    cl_context context;
    cl_platform_id* platforms;
    cl_device_id* devices;
    cl_uint platformcount;
    cl_int ret;
    clGetPlatformIDs(2,NULL,&platformcount);
    clGetPlatformIDs(platformcount,platforms,NULL);
    /*if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("\nNumber of platforms found=%d\n",platformcount);
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

This leads to the core being dumped (Segmentation fault (core dumped)).

```
$ gcc -lOpenCL a.c -o a && ./a
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However, if I comment out the ret declaration the code compiles fine.

```
int main()
{
    cl_context context;
    cl_platform_id* platforms;
    cl_device_id* devices;
    cl_uint platformcount;
    //cl_int ret;
    clGetPlatformIDs(2,NULL,&platformcount);
    clGetPlatformIDs(platformcount,platforms,NULL);
    /*if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("\nNumber of platforms found=%d\n",platformcount);
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: To highlight the code, sorround your code between pair of `

Comment: Ohh. I used ' instead of `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This call

```
clGetPlatformIDs(platformcount,platforms,NULL);
```

writes to where `platforms` points to, but `platforms` had not been initialised to point anywhere, thus the call invokes UB.

Comment: @alk You are right. I got missed between first and second call

Comment: But why does this not cause any error?    '//cl_int ret;
    clGetPlatformIDs(1,NULL,&platformcount);
    //platforms = (cl_platform_id*) malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id) *         platformcount);    
clGetPlatformIDs(platformcount,platforms,NULL);     
/*if(ret==CL_SUCCESS)
{
 printf("\nNumber of platforms found=%d\n",platformcount);
}*/
printf("\nThe code survives!\n"); return 0; }' @alk

Comment: @krish94: The call invokes U(ndefined)B(ehaviour). That means anything could happen: From segmentation violation via restarting your machine to simply nothing.

Comment: And can somebody please tell me how to highlight codes in a comment!